# Can I execute two SCSS file in angular app through angular.json?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, frontend

Can I execute two SCSS file in angular app through angular.json?

1. Is it possible to call two scss files in angular.json
2. we need to call bootstrap.css file in index.html?

If I'm doing the 1st option. I'm getting below error

[image]

Angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "sassTest": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/sassTest",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                            "src/styles.scss"

                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
                        ]
                    },
```

src/style.scss

```
@import './app/footer/footer.component'
```

footer.component.scss

```
@import '../../assets/scss/variable.scss';
.github-star-badge {
    color: $redd;
}
```

variable.scss

```
$redd: #ff0000;
```

Comment: The file path for bootstrap is incorrect, I believe the path should be `../node_modules/...` because you're outputting code to `sassTest` and your node_modules (from what I can tell) are likely not in there.

Comment: Re-phrased question

Comment: When you add in bootstrap.css, change it from a css file to an scss file. I.e. say `.../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss`. I don't think the css file is in the scss folder source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/main/scss

Comment: Pl let me know, Is it possible to execute the two .scss file in angular.json

Comment: SASS gets converted into CSS, so the term "executed" isn't being used quite right. What actually happens is the SASS gets converted into plain CSS which is then "executed" in the browser. With this knowledge in mind, what you can do is `@import` the bootstrap.scss within your main scss file which will essentially merge bootstraps SASS file and the main SASS file giving you one css file as an output. So you can take out the bootstrap SASS file from your angular.json and keep your main scss file and it should work. (not saying it wouldn't work with what is currently setup but this methods better

Comment: To latch on to what I mean by better - I mean that you can adjust variables and other SASS base code from bootstrap.scss when you `@import` it rather than do what you're doing with the angular.json.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can.

Try this one

```
                "styles": [
                    "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                    "src/styles.scss"

                ],
                "scripts": [
                    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
                ]
```